# Possible to ipconfig release/renew for only one nic?

Tags: windows, dhcp, ipconfig

I've got two NICs in my Windows 8 Pro (x64) box each connected to different networks. I would like to release and renew the DHCP lease for just one of the NICs. So far I can't find any way to do it within the `ipconfig` command.

Is this possible? (perhaps another command or GUI even)

[Similar question here](https://superuser.com/questions/19992/ipconfig-for-one-network-adaptor-only), however I'm asking specifically about release/renew functionality.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Yes you can do this.  If you look at `ipconfig /?` you will see the option for `ipconfig /renew [adapter]` and `ipconfig /release [adapter]`.  So you just need to know the adapter name by typing `ipconfig` by itself.

Comment: Thanks, the /? is good to know.

Comment: Windows 10 adds crap to the adapter name that it shows in ipconfig. For instance, ipconfig shows me an entry for ***Wireless LAN adapter Wi-Fi*** but the adapter name that you would supply to `ipconfig /renew` is just ***Wi-Fi***. Remember that it also supports wildcard matches, so I can type `ipconfig /renew *Fi` which works just as well.

Comment: An example: `ipconfig /release "Ethernet 2"`

Answer (score 7):

```
ipconfig /release "adapter name"
ipconfig /renew "adapter name"
```

Answer (score 2):

The name shown by `ipconfig` is - strangely - not the name you supply to the renew and reconfig options, so get the `NetConnectionID` of the NIC using this command in a command window to show you the necessary id to use in the next command, matching the MAC address if necessary:

```
C:\>wmic nic get Name,NetConnectionID,MACAddress
MACAddress         Name                                        NetConnectionID
                   Microsoft Kernel Debug Network Adapter
F8:CA:B8:55:7F:A3  Intel(R) Ethernet Connection (3) I218-LM    Ethernet
10:02:B5:82:71:16  Intel(R) Dual Band Wireless-AC 7265         Wi-Fi
10:02:B5:82:71:1A  Bluetooth Device (Personal Area Network)    Bluetooth Network Connection
```

Then use the name in an `ipconfig` command such as:

```
C:\> ipconfig /release Wi-Fi
C:\> ipconfig /renew Wi-Fi
```

In the example above, `ipconfig` shows the name `Wireless LAN adapter Wi-Fi`, but the name to use with `ipconfig` is just `Wi-Fi` as discovered from the `wmic` command.

Answer (score 0):

Old but this is great info. by using renew /? I actually found you can also do /renew ethernet* and it will reset all adapters starting with ethernet. Pretty cool to know.

```
ipconfig /renew                ... renew all adapters
    > ipconfig /renew EL*            ... renew any connection that has its
                                         name starting with EL
    > ipconfig /release *Con*        ... release all matching connections,
                                         eg. "Wired Ethernet Connection 1" or
                                             "Wired Ethernet Connection 2"
    > ipconfig /allcompartments      ... Show information about all
                                         compartments
    > ipconfig /allcompartments /all ... Show detailed information about all
                                         compartments
```